# Discriminant of quadratic equation with 6 parameters

Tags: quadratics, recreational-mathematics, discriminant

The discriminant of a quadratic polynomial is
$$\Delta=\left(x_2 \left(x_3+x_5\right)+x_4 \left(x_1+x_5\right)+x_6\left(x_1+x_3\right) \right){}^2-4 \left(x_1 x_3+x_3 x_5+x_1 x_5\right) \left(x_2 x_4+x_4 x_6+x_2 x_6\right)$$
with $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_6\} \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$. Prove that also $\Delta  \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ !

A proof was given below in an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4782082/737314). The proof uses inequalities.

**Further question**

Now I want to know if a proof without inequalities is possible. If for example we could finally write $\Delta =a^2+b^2+c^2$ we could directly see that $\Delta \ge 0$. Any other form that avoids inequalities are also acceptable. Inequalities can be used as intermediate steps, but the final form should not contain them. Is a form possible without inequalities?

Comment: Opening everything up (although annoying) first comes to mind.

Comment: What is the indeterminate here? What do you mean by "quadratic equation"?

Comment: @ShyamalSayak https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant

Comment: @granularbastard I understand what discriminant mean. My question is what is your indeterminate here?

Comment: $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_6$

Comment: If $A$, $B,$ $C,$ are suitable symmetric matrices, it is clearly asked to show that $z\mapsto X^T(Az^2+Bz+C)X$ has real roots for all $X\in [0,\infty)^6$. Well, since $A,B,C$ have no clear structure, we need some context for possible help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote $X=(x_1,x_3,x_5)$ and $Y=(x_2,x_4,x_6)$ and $S(X)=(x_1+x_3+x_5).$ Consider the bilinear form $$B(X,Y)=S(X)S(Y)-\langle X,Y\rangle.$$ Then$$\Delta=B(X,Y)^2-B(X,X)B(Y,Y)$$$$=(S(X)\|Y\|-S(Y)\|X\|)^2+(\|X\|\|Y\|-\langle X,Y\rangle)(2S(X)S(Y)-\langle X,Y\rangle-\|X\|\|Y\|)$$From Schwarz $\|X\|\|Y\|-\langle X,Y\rangle>0$ and therefore
$$2S(X)S(Y)-\langle X,Y\rangle-\|X\|\|Y\|\geq 2(S(X)S(Y)-\|X\|\|Y\|)$$ Finally, the fact that $X$ and $Y$ have non negative coefficients implies that $S^2(X)\geq \|X\|^2$, or $S(X)\geq \|X\|$ as well as $S(Y)\geq \|Y\|.$ This proves $\Delta\geq 0.$

For $X,Y\neq 0$, equality $\Delta=0$ takes place if and only if when $\langle X,Y\rangle=\|X\|\|Y\|$ and $S(X)^2=\|X\|^2$ and $S(Y)^2=\|Y\|^2$, namely either $x_3=x_4=x_5=x_6=0$ or $x_1=x_2=x_5=x_6=0$ or $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=0.$

Edit. More generally, if $x$ and $y$ are vectors of $R^n$  with non negative components and with the natural Euclidean structure, defining $S(x)=x_1+\cdots+x_n$ then $B(x,y)=S(x)S(y)-\langle x,y\rangle$ still satisfies $B(x,y)^2\geq B(x,x)B(y,y)$. If you prefer matrices, introduce $I_n$ the identity matrix and $J_n$ the matrix whose all entries are $1$  and observe that $B(x,y)=x^T(J_n-I_n)y.$

Comment: This is a very nice problem after all.

Comment: Because it seems ugly and without structure, which is not true, and not restricted to 6 variables, but extendable to $R^n$ instead of $R^3.$ and thus to $2n$ variables. What is the source of the problem?

Comment: Is it possible to write the answer as squared sum in the form $\Delta=a^2+b^2+c^2$ or similar form, so that we do not have to consider inequalities? The question stems from an Eigenvalue problem.

Comment: I think not, since it is based also on $S^2(X)-\|X\|^2>0$ which is true because $x_i>0.$ Of  course if $A>0$ you can write it as a square $(\sqrt{A})^2$ but I don't think that this is what you have in mind.